# How to stop mediaplayer upon accessing another fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-mediaplayer

This is the fragment class

```
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View layoutView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_lyrics,
            container, false);
    int hymnNo = fragVal - 1;
            //Database
    final MediaPlayer p = MediaPlayer.create(getActivity(), R.raw.s);

    final ToggleButton playPauseButton = 
    (ToggleButton)layoutView.findViewById(R.id.playpause);
    playPauseButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {

            if (playPauseButton.isChecked() ){

                p.start();
            }else{
                p.pause();
            }

        }});
```

I have things in mind..how can my mediaplayer from this fragment be stop once i go to another fragment? and totally reset it(current fragment), meaning my toggle button will also be in its default position?
ive tried

```
   public void onDetach()
   {
   getActivity().finish();}
```

its not working..my idea is to destroy all fragments that are not visible.
i also tried using the one with the use of visibility but i dont have any idea how to call the mediaplayer (i.e p.release() or p.stop() in a fragment life cycle such as the onDestroy or onDetach..please help me guyz..i have ideas but dont know how to do it.

Answer (score -1):

Try this.

```
    @Override 
    public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) { 
        super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
        if (isVisibleToUser) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Visible");

             //your code

        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "Not Visible");

               if (mPlayer != null){
                mPlayer.release();

                Log.d(TAG, "Player released");


            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: That would be helpful to add some details about your [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) instead of 'try this'.